# Нужно решить с помощью Си

Tags: c

Даны два действительных числа. Выяснить, одного знака эти числа.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
main()
{
    double a, b;
    printf("a="); scanf_s("%lf", &a);
    printf("b="); scanf_s("%lf", &b);
    if (a < b)
    {
        printf("a < b");
    }
    if (a > b)
    {
        printf("a > b");
    }
    if (a = b)
    {
        printf("a = b");
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Окей, и какие у вас проблемы с этим кодом?

Comment: Можете написать свою версию этой программы на Си ?

Comment: Чтобы выяснить знак чисел, нужно сравнивать их с нулём, а не друг с другом

Comment: А библиотек то зачем столько???? 0_о

Comment: `int samesign = (a < 0.0 && b < 0.0) || (a >= 0.0 && b >= 0.0);`

Comment: Чую, что-то не так. Вот так:  `samesign = (a < 0.0) == (b < 0.0);` значительно эффективней

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да просто перемножить - если получится положительное значение, значит - одного, отрицательное - разных знаков...

Нуль - значит, одно из чисел нулевое, тут сами решайте - какой знак у нуля :)

Написать сами напишете? :)

P.S. Если боитесь переполнения при умножении - то можно воспользоваться чем-то типа `signbit()` или набросать функцию получения знака...

Comment: Может так: `samesign = (a < 0.0) == (b < 0.0)` эффективней будет?

Comment: @avp Любая задача решается множеством методов :)